# Out of memory exception only on Android 2.3

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android app which has lots of images. It works fine on all latest versions of android except 2.3. Here is my code:

```
if (mBitmap != null) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
            mBitmap = null;
        }

        //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);                                                         

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mRealPaint = new Paint();
        mRealPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mRealPaint.setDither(true);
        mRealPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRealPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRealPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.BEVEL);
        mRealPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mRealPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
```

Here is stacktrace:

```
06-30 15:10:53.252: E/dalvikvm-heap(987): 460800-byte external allocation too large for this process.
06-30 15:10:53.252: E/GraphicsJNI(987): VM won't let us allocate 460800 bytes
06-30 15:10:53.260: D/AndroidRuntime(987): Shutting down VM
06-30 15:10:53.270: W/dalvikvm(987): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7393)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.nova.picturepattern.common.view.DrawCharView.showStroke(DrawCharView.java:299)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.nova.picturepattern.common.view.DrawCharView.touch_move(DrawCharView.java:155)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.nova.picturepattern.common.view.DrawCharView.onTouchEvent(DrawCharView.java:230)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-30 15:10:53.371: E/AndroidRuntime(987):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 15:10:56.881: W/webcore(987): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
06-30 15:10:58.751: I/Process(987): Sending signal. PID: 987 SIG: 9
```

Can someone please guide me what am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333878/bitmap-out-of-memory-exception/17334330#17334330.

Comment: @Raghunandan - I added recycle from above link. It works for other android versions now but still does not work for 2.3.

Comment: scaled down the images and try

Comment: When you say it doesn't work in Android 2.3, aren't you leaving out other factors, e.g .amount of RAM the device has, screen sizes, etc.? That would be more likely IMHO.

Comment: @Raghunandan - What you mean by scale down the images? Should i change 320, 480 to 240, 320??

Comment: @NoviceMe check the docs http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

"Mostly" gingerbread devices has low Heap size therefore your app will crash unless if you reduces the bitmap size. inSampleSize = 6 and bove; is preferred for old devices. even tho some new devices like "HTC" brand, the heap size still low therefore your app will crash. what i'm doing is. if the user phone heap size is low i reduce the image quality to avoid out of memory issue.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you are doing this? Or show me your code?