# Image value null on taking picture in android

Tags: android, image, camera

I've been working with this android app(Not my codes) now i just found a problem when i'm taking a picture. "it is working fine on Samsung Note 10.1 tablet" but when i tried it in my phone the app stops when i will take a picture. i'm stuck here for days now searching for solutions and i don't know where to trace the problem anymore.

I debugged the program and found that the image is null. but the data has values. this the code where i found the problem

```
private Camera.PictureCallback takePictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.v(TAG,"takePictureCallback.onPictureTaken");
        Bitmap image = processImage(data);

        if(mTakePictureListener!=null){
            mTakePictureListener.onTakePicture(image);
        }
    }
};
```

i'm sorry that this is confusing because i can't explain the details well enough. i would really appreciate some help. you can ask me for more information if you want.

Here is the logcat

```
10-27 09:02:22.593    1664-1664/com.project.app V/CameraPreview﹕ preview started
10-27 09:02:22.593    1664-1664/com.project.app V/CameraPreview﹕ SurfaceChanged finished
10-27 09:02:31.121    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
10-27 09:02:31.121    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
10-27 09:02:31.121    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
10-27 09:02:31.121    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 480`
10-27 09:02:31.121    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 24
10-27 09:02:31.121    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
10-27 09:02:31.431    1664-1664/com.project.app V/CameraPreview﹕ postPreview.onPictureTaken
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at capture.CameraPreview.processImage(CameraPreview.java:90)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at capture.CameraPreview.access$200(CameraPreview.java:27)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at capture.CameraPreview$3.onPictureTaken(CameraPreview.java:65)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-27 09:02:31.461    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:31.471    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
10-27 09:02:31.471    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
10-27 09:02:31.471    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 480
10-27 09:02:31.471    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 0
10-27 09:02:31.471    1664-1664/com.project.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
10-27 09:02:31.852    1664-1664/com.project.app V/CameraPreview﹕ takePictureCallback.onPictureTaken
10-27 09:02:31.902    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 36.449MB for 19660816-byte allocation
10-27 09:02:31.932    1664-1673/com.project.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 13% free 36412K/41608K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
10-27 09:02:31.952    1664-1673/com.project.app D/AbsListView﹕ [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-27 09:02:31.952    1664-1673/com.project.app I/MotionRecognitionManager﹕ .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,
10-27 09:02:31.952    1664-1673/com.project.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-27 09:02:31.952    1664-1673/com.project.app D/AbsListView﹕ [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-27 09:02:31.952    1664-1673/com.project.app I/MotionRecognitionManager﹕ .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,
10-27 09:02:31.952    1664-1673/com.project.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-27 09:02:31.972    1664-1668/com.project.app E/dalvikvm﹕ adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
10-27 09:02:31.972    1664-1668/com.project.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 790K, 15% free 35625K/41608K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 41ms
10-27 09:02:32.242    1664-1664/com.project.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4325K, 25% free 31300K/41608K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
10-27 09:02:32.242    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 14745616-byte allocation
10-27 09:02:32.272    1664-1664/com.project.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 11K, 25% free 31289K/41608K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
10-27 09:02:32.272    1664-1664/com.project.app E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 14745616-byte allocation.
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x419199a0 self=0x41909300
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=1664 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075561948
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1561 stm=218 core=0
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:718)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:695)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:628)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at capture.CameraPreview.processImage(CameraPreview.java:94)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at capture.CameraPreview.access$200(CameraPreview.java:27)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at capture.CameraPreview$2.onPictureTaken(CameraPreview.java:51)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:846)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 10-27 09:02:32.282  1664: 1664 W/System.err ]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:718)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:695)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:628)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at capture.CameraPreview.processImage(CameraPreview.java:94)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at capture.CameraPreview.access$200(CameraPreview.java:27)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at capture.CameraPreview$2.onPictureTaken(CameraPreview.java:51)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:846)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-27 09:02:32.282    1664-1664/com.project.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 09:02:32.292    1664-1664/com.project.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-27 09:02:32.292    1664-1664/com.project.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41918930)
10-27 09:02:32.332    1664-1664/com.project.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at capture.CaptureFragment.bitmapToFile(CaptureFragment.java:544)
        at capture.CaptureFragment.access$100(CaptureFragment.java:65)
        at capture.CaptureFragment$2.onTakePicture(CaptureFragment.java:117)
        at capture.CameraPreview$2.onPictureTaken(CameraPreview.java:54)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:846)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the codes for the CameraPreview

```
private AutoFocusCallback onFocus = new AutoFocusCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        justTakeTheDamPicture();
    }

};

private Camera.PictureCallback takePictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.v(TAG,"takePictureCallback.onPictureTaken");
        Bitmap image = processImage(data);

        if(mTakePictureListener!=null){
            mTakePictureListener.onTakePicture(image);
        }
    }
};

private Camera.PictureCallback postPreviewCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.v(TAG,"postPreview.onPictureTaken");
        if(data!=null){
            Bitmap image = processImage(data);

            if(mTakePictureListener!=null){
                mTakePictureListener.onPostPreview(image);
            }
        }
    }
};

private Bitmap processImage(byte[] data){
    try{
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Bitmap croppedImage = null;
        Bitmap resizedImage = null;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.postRotate(90);


        if(image.getHeight()>image.getWidth()){
            croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0,(image.getHeight()/2)-(image.getWidth()/2),image.getWidth(), image.getWidth(),matrix,false);
            resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedImage, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, false);
        }else{
            croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, (image.getWidth()/2)-(image.getHeight()/2),0,image.getHeight(), image.getHeight(),matrix,false);
            resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedImage, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, false);
        }
        long croppingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - currTime;
        Log.v(TAG,"Cropping time: "+croppingTime);
        return resizedImage;
    }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),R.string.out_of_memory, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return null;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return null;
    }
}


private Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        if(mTakePictureListener!=null)
            mTakePictureListener.onShutter();
    }

};
private static String TAG = "CameraPreview";

public interface TakePictureListener{
    public void onTakePicture(Bitmap bitmap);
    public void onPostPreview(Bitmap image);
    public void onShutter();
}
public CameraPreview(Context context,SurfaceView surfaceView,FrameLayout surfaceFrame) {
    super(context);

    mSurfaceView = surfaceView;
    mSurfaceFrame = surfaceFrame;

    setFrameSize();
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    Log.v(TAG,"Contructor finished");
}

 private void justTakeTheDamPicture(){
    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, postPreviewCallback, takePictureCallback);
}

private void setCameraParameters() {

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    if(mPreviewSizes==null)
        mPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    if(mPreviewSize==null){
        for(Camera.Size size : mPreviewSizes){
            if(mPreviewSize==null || mPreviewSize.width<size.width){
                mPreviewSize = size;
                if(mPreviewSize.width>mScreenSize.x) break;
            }
        }
    }



    Log.v(TAG,"Preview Size: "+mPreviewSize.width+"x"+mPreviewSize.height);

    LayoutParams surfaceViewParams = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    float scaleFactor = 0;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
    {   // If API >= 8 -> rotate display...
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        // when rotated, need to interchange
        scaleFactor = (float)mFrameSize/mPreviewSize.height;
        surfaceViewParams.width = (int) (mPreviewSize.height*scaleFactor);
        surfaceViewParams.height = (int) (mPreviewSize.width*scaleFactor);
    }else{
        scaleFactor = (float)mFrameSize/mPreviewSize.width;
        surfaceViewParams.width = (int) (mPreviewSize.width*scaleFactor);
        surfaceViewParams.height = (int) (mPreviewSize.height*scaleFactor);
    }



    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(surfaceViewParams);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

    if(parameters.getFocusMode()!=null){
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    }
    if(parameters.getFlashMode()!=null){
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    }
    // Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE does not work on some samsung devices
    // so try and catch the error and revert to Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO
    try{
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

private void setFrameSize() {

    LayoutParams surfaceLayoutParams = mSurfaceFrame.getLayoutParams();

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    mScreenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(mScreenSize);

    mFrameSize = mScreenSize.x;

    surfaceLayoutParams.width = mFrameSize;
    surfaceLayoutParams.height = mFrameSize;

    mSurfaceFrame.setLayoutParams(surfaceLayoutParams);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int format, int width, int height) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    if(mCamera!=null){

        setCameraParameters();

        // Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface.
        // Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.v(TAG,"preview started");
    }
    Log.v(TAG,"SurfaceChanged finished");
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(mCamera != null)
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }  
    Log.v(TAG,"SurfaceDestroyed finished");
}

/**
 * When this function returns, mCamera will be null.
 */
private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

    if (mCamera != null) {
        // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
        // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
        // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
        mCamera.release();

        mCamera = null;
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {

        stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        setCameraParameters();


    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if(mCamera!=null){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void takePicture(){
    if(mCamera!=null){
        try{
            if(mCamera.getParameters().getFocusMode()==Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE){
                mCamera.autoFocus(onFocus);
            }else{
                justTakeTheDamPicture();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            justTakeTheDamPicture();
        }
    }
}

public void setTakePictureListener(TakePictureListener l){
    mTakePictureListener = l;
}

public Camera getCamera(){
    return mCamera;
}
```

Here are the codes for the Capture Fragment

```
private OnClickListener onCapture = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mPreview!=null){
            mPreview.takePicture();
        }

    }

};
private CameraPreview.TakePictureListener takePictureListener = new CameraPreview.TakePictureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTakePicture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Capture cap = Capture.getInstance(getActivity());
        cap.setUri(bitmapToFile(bitmap));
        //cap.save();
        showLastCroppped();
        changeCaptureStatus(CaptureStatus.HasImageNoFields);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        changeCaptureStatus(CaptureStatus.TakingPicture);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostPreview(Bitmap image) {
        imagePreviewContainer.setImageBitmap(image);
        imagePreviewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};

private Uri bitmapToFile(Bitmap bmp){
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
            "/Alliwant";

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy-hhmmss.SSS");

    File dir = new File(file_path);
    if(!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();
    String filename = simpleDate.format( new Date() );
    File file = new File(dir, "gift" + filename + ".png");

    FileOutputStream fOut;
    Uri fileUri = null;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);

    try {
        fOut.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    try {
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return fileUri;
}
```

Comment: processImage() code and Logcat exception log?

Comment: @Goyzki : `java.lang.NullPointerException at capture.CaptureFragment.bitmapToFile(CaptureFragment.java:544)` what else can you possibly need?

Comment: @njzk2, i just edited the logcat, i can see the image value was null but i don't know why.

Comment: CaptureFragment.java:544 referred to this code bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);

the problem with that code is that the bitmap is null.

Comment: there is an outofmemoryerror, too

Comment: my memory is also fine, i have a blank sd card installed and my device storage is not full. it can save the image file but it is corrupted. is it possible that the cause is in the resolution or image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was indeed a out of memory problem, processing bitmaps takes a lot of memory allocation, specially images with large sizes(just like mine that was 1920). i was able to solve it by allowing by application to use large heap of memory, adding one line to the android manifest in the application tag.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

i don't know if this is the best approach to solve the problem, but i find it a good approach because i don't have to compromise changing the size already set. please comment if you have a better solution. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your system memory (not disk space) is running out, resulting in OOM error.

Check your calls to

```
    Bitmap.createBitmap
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap
```

consider reducing the bitmap sizes, or [see this for one approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333878/bitmap-out-of-memory-exception)